# Can I operate a drone without connecting to the Matrix using an RCC?

Tags: equipment, shadowrun-sr5, drones

I'm not sure if I got this right from the book, but seems that I need to be, at least, connected with my drones at the AR level, right? Can I operate it without connecting to the Matrix using an RCC?

Comment: Is the drone big enough to have a cockpit attached, or otherwise carry around your insensate body while your mind is driving it around?

Comment: In what sense does this affect the situation?

Comment: @BrunoEstraulas Because if not, you're going to have to connect wirelessly, via connecting to the Matrix, or the drone will be tethered to your body by the cable you're plugging into it with.

Comment: @nick012000 so it seems that I need to connect through the Matrix or directly using a cable. In Shadowrun there isn't such thing as a local wireless network without the "Matrix Internet", right? Everything is connected to the Matrix the whole time. But if I'm in a static zone, with no chance to connect to Matrix, I also cannot connect to my drones wirelessly?